# Convert byte* {aka unsigned char*}’ to ‘byte [32] {aka unsigned char [32]}

Tags: c++, c++11, crypto++

I am using [Crypto++ Salsa20](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Salsa20) as a part of my project. The above link has an example code in which they define

```
byte key[32];
```

So I have a string of 64 bytes. I got this value from SHA256. Basically they are hexal values. So I believe this can be stored in key.

```
string hashVal = "b684f0912266e387eded257b8107b6fc65f0ed97773ecb09078c9a8004d08563";
```

I need to store this value into key[32]. I tried my best to convert the string into key but never got through.

```
byte *plaintextBytes = (byte *) hashVal.c_str();
OR
byte *plaintextBytes = new byte[hashVal.length()];
key = passphraseBytes;
```

Can anyone please help me address this issue.

Comment: Are you just expermenting with Salsa20 or tryting to use secure encryption?

Comment: I am experimenting with Salsa20 as a part of my class project. Like the key is used as the passphrase to encrypt and decrypt the messages.

Comment: You would probably do well to study encoding such as hexadicimal, binary, Base64, ASCII and unicode.

Comment: That looks like more than 32 characters in `hashVal` ... maybe you also want to do a "hex-to-binary" conversion

Comment: @sickJuice - M.M. is likely right - you need to run you ASCII data through a [`HexDecoder`](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/HexDecoder), and then use the binary data. The Crypto++ wiki also has an example of using Salsa at [Salsa20](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Salsa20). Its not that good of a page at the moment. Let me see if I can improve the documentation for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use memcpy:

```
std::memcpy(key, &hashVal[0], std::min(32, hashVal.size());
```

This is assuming you don't need a null terminator.

Comment: Awesome thanks!!! 
I tried this but ended up having an extra 'p' stored at end memcpy(key, shaval.c_str(), 32);
Your logic worked like a charm. Thanks @Crazy Eddie

Also if you can help I want to convert the hashVal string into a another string. As you would have noticed the the hashVal string is actually a hex string. So I want to convert the hex values and store them in a string(as two hex values form an ascii char). Any suggestions.